# How to detect link in the textarea and make them in <a href=" ">

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Recently I'm creating a social network website like facebook. But i have a problem. In my social network users can create posts. So if user enter a link in the textarea of the post i need to make them as the  (look like a link). So what i need from you guys is, help to auto detect the user inputted link and make them look like this -  [https://www.google.com][1]

Here is my code,

```
<textarea placeholder="What's On Your Mind? " name="text"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
$('#post-body').on('change', function(e) {
  var target = e.target,
    position = target.selectionStart; // Capture initial position
  target.value = linkify(this.value); // This triggers the cursor to move.
  target.selectionEnd = position; // Set the cursor back to the initial position.
});

function linkify(inputText) {
  var replacedText, replacePattern1, replacePattern2, replacePattern3;
  replacePattern1 = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;
  replacedText = inputText.replace(replacePattern1, '[$1][1]');
  replacePattern2 = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
  replacedText = replacedText.replace(replacePattern2, '[$2][1]');
  return replacedText;
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter something like 'www.google.com' then click outside the textarea
<textarea id="post-body"></textarea>
```

Comment: but that's not a link

Comment: @RickPensi Didn't you ask me to make them like that? "... and make them look like this - [https://www.google.com][1]"

Answer (score 0):

Just modified @spectric code to return href code only.

```js
$('#post-body').on('change', function(e) {
  var target = e.target,
    position = target.selectionStart; // Capture initial position
  target.value = linkify(this.value); // This triggers the cursor to move.
  target.selectionEnd = position; // Set the cursor back to the initial position.
});

function linkify(inputText) {
  var replacedText, replacePattern1, replacePattern2, replacePattern3;
  replacePattern1 = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;
  replacedText = inputText.replace(replacePattern1, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
  
  replacePattern2 = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
  replacedText = replacedText.replace(replacePattern2, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
  return replacedText;
}
```

```css
textarea{
height: 200px;
width: 500px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="post-body" placeholder="insert links or something"></textarea>
```